# Generated von neumann algebra and commutant

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $(\mathfrak{M}_i, \mathcal{H})_i$ a family of Von neumann algebras acting on the same Hilbert space.
The von Neumann algebra

$$\bigcup_{i}\mathfrak{M}_i = \bigcap\{\mathfrak{M} \, : \, \mathfrak{M} \supset \mathfrak{M}_i \, \, \, \forall i\}$$

is called the generated von neumann algebra by $\mathfrak{M}_i$.

I need to prove that $(\bigcup_i \mathfrak{M}_i)' = \bigcap \mathfrak{M}_i'$ and $(\bigcap_i \mathfrak{M}_i)' = \bigcup_i \mathfrak{M}_i'$     (The commutants)

how may I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Comment: the notation for the von Neumann algebra generated is terrible, as now you have no notation for the union. I will use the union as a union.*

Notation: $W^*(S)$ is the von Neumann algebra generated by the set $S$. It is easy to check that $S'=W^*(S)'$: we have $S'=S'''=(S'')'=W^*(S)'$. So you actually only need to do your argument with the union, and not with the algebra generated.

Suppose that $T\in (\bigcup_j M_j)'$. Then, $T\in M_j'$ for any $j$, so $T\in\bigcap_jM_j'$. Conversely, if $T\in \bigcap_jM_j'$ then $T\in M_j'$ for all $j$; so $T\in(\bigcup_jM_j)'$.

Now, using the first equality.
$$
W^*\Big(\bigcup_jM_j\Big)=\Big(\bigcup_jM_j\Big)'' =\Big[\big(\bigcup_jM_j\big)'\Big]'=\Big[\bigcap_jM_j'\Big]'
$$

---

**Edit:** *proof that the von Neumann algebra generated by a selfadjoint set $S\subset B(H)$ is $S''$.*

Since $S''$ is a von Neumann algebra and it contains $S$, then $W^*(S)\subset S''$. Conversely, since $S\subset W^*(S)$, then $W^*(S)'\subset S'$, so $S''\subset W^*(S)''=W^*(S)$.

Comment: is the union of von neumann algebras a von neumann algebra?

Comment: No. In general, a union of subspaces is not a subspace.

Comment: how to prove that both the definitions of generated algebra are equivalent? I mean the bicommutant and the intersection of all von neumann algebras which contain the first one

Comment: It's the first thing you prove after the double commutant theorem. I included two lines in the answer at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MartinArgerami Where did you use the "self-adjointness" of $S$ in the proof of the fact that: "von Neumann algebra generated by a selfadjoint set $S$ is $S''$? " It seems the proof works for **any** subset $S$ of $B(H)$....Isn't that?

Comment: @indrajit: No. If $S$ is not selfajoint there is no reason for $S''$ to be a $*$-algebra.

Comment: I understand. Thank you